# Facebook Video Like Button Help?

Tags: video, facebook, facebook-like

So I posted a video on my Facebook profile wall. It has a few Likes. I want to take that video, and post it on my personal website with a Like button. **Is that possible?**

**If it is, would Liking the video on my website, and Liking the video on my profile do the same thing?** (Or would they be two separate Like counters?)

Thanks.

Comment: I think http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for getting answers on this question.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a video from your Facebook page or your profile that video gets "*Like button*"
included.

It is not possible to add one more like button inside that video.

The `<html>` page of your site in which you are planning to embed this video, here in that page you can add one more "like button", at that time both likes are different, but the second "like button" which you had added in your html file, will share the url of your site.