# How to embed video with like button

Tags: facebook, video

I noticed some videos on facebook that have a like button embedded into the video.

I was wondering how I can do the with mine?

Comment: Please send an example of this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The middle response of [Facebook Video Like Button Help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892043/facebook-video-like-button-help) seems to indicate Facebook will automatically embed a like button into the video you upload to them (rather than linking to an external video).

Also this article seems to confirm it: http://yourinternetbusinesslink.com/facebook-like-button-video/

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit of late response but I have just been asked the same question from a client. I found this video explaining how the Facebook Like is implemented in your videos and is definitely worth a watch: https://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=1594767623585

Basically, this feature is automatically added to your videos when you upload your videos to your **Fan Page's Video Tab** (not your personal profile but your fan pages video tab).

I hope this helps =)